# Path to image in Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, postman

I'm working on a project that involves both front-end (react.js) and back-end (node.js). The back-end had been uploaded to AWS.

I'm trying to fetch an image stored in the back-end.

Assuming the path to the image in AWS is : `/home/ubuntu/path/to/image.jpg`

and the url for the back-end is: `123.123.123.123:4000`

How can I fetch the image?

Running a `GET` request in Postman with the following url -

```
http://123.123.123.123:4000/home/ubuntu/path/to/image.jpg
```

resolves in a `Cannot GET` error.

Comment: you cannot access the image directly. you will have to setup server apache2 or Nginx or any other server an then expose a folder as public.

Answer (score 0):

Usually any files you wish to serve need to be in the web root of the server. You don't say, at all, how your AWS Ubuntu server is configured so it is really hard to say what the path should be.

In general though the web root would be something like `/var/www/public/` - so using that as an example you would need to move your images into this path - e.g. `/var/www/public/path/to/image.jpg`

Then the URL to the image would be `123.123.123.123:4000/path/to/image.jpg`

In general, without an Alias or symlink with FollowSymLinks or some such, any file you wish to serve needs to be in the web root of the server and resources outside of this path are not web accessible - for obvious security reasons.

You could try and Alias the path to your images into the web root i.e. `Alias /home/ubuntu/path/to/ /var/www/public/images/` which *should* make the path to the image `123.123.123.123:4000/images/image.jpg` however, again, this would depend on your server set-up.